# How do I get the difference in time in nanoseconds? Problem in types (Rust)

Tags: rust

I have a bit of of a problem regarding types in rust.
In my problem, I am simulating message transferring in a graph.

I have the speed at which a message can be transferred in M/s (Megabits/seconds) along a channel and I also have the message size in M (Megabits). To get the time at which the message arrive is pretty standard: size/speed.

I am now trying to get the difference in time in nanoseconds between the time that the message was sent and the time now. I want it in nanoseconds because if the message is very small then the time for transferring will also be very small.

If I want to get number of milliseconds from the difference in time then I can get it with the function `diff.num_milliseconds()` which gives me a `i64` type.

However if I want to get the number of nanoseconds from the difference then `diff.num_nanoseconds()` returns a type `Option<i64>` and you can't seem to compare a float with `Option<i64>`.

```
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;
use chrono::{Utc};


fn main() {
    // size of message in M
    let size = 0.05;

    // transfer speed in M/s
    let speed = 1e6;

    // speed in M/ns
    let speed_nano = speed/1e9;

    let now = Utc::now();

    let sec = Duration::from_millis(5000);
    thread::sleep(sec);
    
    let then = Utc::now();

    let diff = then-now;

    println!("{}",(size/speed_nano) < diff.num_nanoseconds());
}
```

What am I missing here? How can I properly do the comparison?

Comment: Presumably there is something the compiler complains about, or ...?

Comment: Your headline asks "How to get nanosecond timestamps", but your content asks "how do I compare `Option<i64>` and `f32`". Which one is it? Because they have quite different answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Option<i64>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) means that the function returns a value that contains either an `i64` or nothing at all. You get either a `Some(an_i64)` or `None`, which represents the absence of an `i64` value.

You can extract the `i64` (if it's there) using [`unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap), for example:

```
(size/speed_nano) < diff.num_nanoseconds().unwrap()
```

If there's no `i64` value there, `unwrap` will panic and terminate your program. You can also use [`unwrap_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or) to supply a default value:

```
(size/speed_nano) < diff.num_nanoseconds().unwrap_or(0)
```

---

You can't compare a float to an `Option<i64>` because it doesn't make sense: how would a float compare to a *missing*, "nonexistent" value `None`?

```
fn is_less(a: f64, b: Option<i64>) -> bool {
    match b {
        Some(my_integer) => a < my_integer,
        None => ?????
    }
}
```

In that case, the float `a` is not less than `None`, but it's also not equal to it and not greater, so what is it? Rust decided that it's an error.